# Do browsers process javascript functions faster when variables have smaller names?

Tags: javascript

Load time and readability not withstanding, do browsers process JavaScript functions faster if the variable names are smaller.

For example is:

```
function a(b,c,d){
    return b+c+d;
}
```

faster than

```
function addThreeNumbers(number1, number2, number3){
    return number1 + number2 + number3;
}
```

Comment: Discounting load times? No. The code is parsed only once, independent of how it is executed. It *could* make a difference with object property names (e.g. in highly dynamic code that the JITter couldn't optimize), though, but probably not to the point it matters.

Comment: Even if you were to INCLUDE load times, the difference would be so small that it'd be difficult to measure, unless you were loading hundreds of thousands of lines of javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've set up a test to show that indeed, the length of your variable names don't make a difference:

http://jsperf.com/long-vs-short-variable-names

Comment: As always, the only way to truly answer a question like this is to measure.  +1.

Comment: The long executed 100k less the first test, 12k less the second test, and 353k less the last one, very inconsistent.

Comment: @DanielWeiner I realized that as you posted, -1 removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can find shorter variable names faster, but only if you have atomic clock to measure it :) If your web application is slow, try to find bottleneck somewhere else.

Comment: ...and this still only matters at the initial page load, not during execution.

Comment: But to measure start the atomic clock at the exact moment the code is executed, you'll need an atomic wire to transmit the signal at the exact time.  But then you need to record the time at the exact moment which requires an atomic reaction time...  Then, you need to repeat that 3 times using each of the codebits so the data used to statistically accurate...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count load times as speed, then yes, it will load smaller names fatser, but if not, it won't have ***Any*** effet, as @Tom said, it's parsed once, then stored as a memory value. In terms of the function running, alot of short names (like `100` + is better than the same amount of long, like `15` character names. Here's an example.

```
window.randomInteger = function(minimumValueUsedToCalculateTheMinimumInTheRandomNumber, MaximumValueUsedToCalculateTheMaximumInTheRandomNumber) {
    var randomNumberThatWasGenerated = Math.floor((Math.random()) * (MaximumValueUsedToCalculateTheMaximumInTheRandomNumber - minimumValueUsedToCalculateTheMinimumInTheRandomNumber) +1) + minimumValueUsedToCalculateTheMinimumInTheRandomNumber;
    return randomNumberThatWasGenerated;
}
```

Will be somewhat slower loading than the equivalent:

```
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random()) * (max - min) +1) + min;
}
```

But generally the difference is only a few milliseconds, so irrelevant.

Comment: "Will be much slower loading and executing than the equalivent:" not so much on the execution...execution will stay the same no matter if you're using 3000 character variables or 1 character.  Also not MUCH slower on the loading either...